# Check if there is no application.conf

Tags: java, configuration, typesafe

How can I check if my Spark application have no application.conf?

I read this conf with:

```java
Config configuracion = ConfigFactory.load();
```

But when I check:

```java
if (null != configuracion && !configuracion.isEmpty() && !configuracion.entrySet().isEmpty()){
    config_exists = true;
}
```

It always return config_exists=true.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ConfigFactory.load()` loads the system properties. Therefore the resulting `Config` object is not empty.

I have a hack for you, there might be a simpler way I don't know about.

```java
Config conf = ConfigFactory.load();

// create a config containing only the system properties
Config emptyConfig = ConfigFactory.systemProperties();

// check that the loaded config is not equal to this "empty config"
Boolean isDefinedConfig = ! conf.equals(emptyConfig);
```